# AWS Kinesis Boto3 IAM permisisons

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

Imagine I have two streams, `staging` and `prod`.

I also have an AWS Lambda functions that is using `boto3` to interact with Kinesis. The constraint here is that the Lambda should only be able to interact with the `staging` stream.

The role used by the Lambda has the following policy:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:ListStreams",
                "kinesis:DescribeStream"
                "kinesis:ListShards",
                "kinesis:GetShardIterator"
                "kinesis:GetRecord",
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-central-1:xxx:stream/staging"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

I can't call `kinesis_client.list_streams(ExclusiveStartStreamName="staging")` because I get an error saying that the role used is not allowed to `kinesis:ListStreams` on the `prod` stream.

Is there any way to accomplish this without being to permissive?

I've used the following policy:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:*",
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

But I would prefer a way of not opening the permissions so much.

Comment: You contradict your self. You write that the role should be "able to interact with the staging stream". So why would it work with `prod` stream?

Comment: That's exactly my problem. Like I also mentioned in the question:

I can't call kinesis_client.list_streams(ExclusiveStartStreamName="staging") because I get an error saying that the role used is not allowed to kinesis:ListStreams on the prod stream.

Comment: Not sure why a lambda needs to access both staging and prod, but you could add another statement allowing only kinesis:ListStreams on prod resource.

Comment: That's the problem, I want this lambda to only access staging, yet, I can't do that, because boto3 complains about not having access to the prod stream. Which I do not want.

Comment: You might want to try call the kinesis list stream API with `Limit=1`. Based on what I'm in reading in the docs, the `ExclusiveStartStreamName` allows you to list all the names of streams starting with "staging" but doesn't stop it from listing all streams so by setting Limit=1, it'll list only the staging stream and then stop therefore preventing the mentioned error.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following statement to your policy to just allow ListStreams for the prod one.

```
    {
        "Action": [
            "kinesis:ListStreams"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-central-1:xxx:stream/prod”
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I do not want. Like I mentioned in the question, `The constraint here is that the Lambda should only be able to interact with the staging stream.`.

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking then tbh. That permission isn’t giving any permissions for you lambda to interact with the prod stream at all, just acknowledge it’s existence when it lists the streams under the hood.

Comment: Amusing how you are so concerned about that but you have prod and staging in the same account